# exception handling in WinJS script

Tags: c#, windows-8, winjs

I am calling a function in C# code from my JavaScript (in my windows 8 application)which fetches some values from the service and returns it back to JavaScript. I need to handle the error which is thrown from C# code in my JavaScript call method.Please let me know if it is possible . A code sample would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions in WinJS when calling an external library are handled the "JavaScript" way.
 An example is:

```
try {
    //Run some code here
    TestClassLibrary.Class1.runMe();
}
catch (err) {
    //Handle errors here
    console.log(err.message);
}
```

For the simple C# class:

```
namespace TestClassLibrary
{
   sealed public class  Class1
    {
        public static void RunMe()
        {
            throw new Exception("something is wrong!!");
        }
    }
}
```

You'll get the following message in your console:

```
System.Exception: something is wrong!!
   at TestClassLibrary.Class1.RunMe()
```

Note: Be sure your Class is marked as **sealed**, and your project output is **WinMD**

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at the error strategy implemented in the **Windows.Networking.Sockets** namespace.

They have a **SocketError class** which has a static **method getStatus(hresult)** and it returns a **SocketErrorStatus enumeration**.

You can implement custom exceptions with custom HRESULT codes (must be negative though) for example:

```
public class TestException : Exception
{
 /// <summary>
 /// Constructs the exception from a string message
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="message">error description</param>
 public TestException(String message)
 : base(message)
 {
   base.HResult = -1001;
 }
}
```

You will also provide a class TestError that depending on the hresult will return a member of your TestErrorStatus enumeration which can look like:

```
namespace TestClassLibrary
{
    public enum TestErrorStatus
    {
        TestError = -1001
    }
}
```

And in your WinJS code you will check:

```
function (error) {
 var errorStatus = TestClassLibrary.TestError.getStatus(error.number);
 if (errorStatus == TestClassLibrary.TestErrorStatus.TestError) {
  // error is TestException
 } 
}
```